# How to access elements nested in UIStackView within MkMapView for UITests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, uitest

I want to write UI tests for views inside a `UIStackView` thats inside a `MKMapView`.
Here's a snippet of the MWE. I created a `MKMapView` added a `UIStackView` with two `UIView`s as subviews.

```swift
let map = MKMapView()
let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
map.addSubview(stackView)
view.addSubview(map)
```

And I declared an `accessibilityIdentifier` for each element and set the `isAccessibilityElement` attribute to true.

```swift
view1.accessibilityIdentifier = "view1"
view2.accessibilityIdentifier = "view2"
stackView.accessibilityIdentifier = "stackView"
view1.isAccessibilityElement = true
view2.isAccessibilityElement = true
stackView.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

However, there are no subviews of the stack view visible in the app element subtree nor are they accessible.
You can see the `UIStackView` with the identifier 'stackView' but not the `UIViews`.

```
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x6000030080e0, pid: 11856, label: 'UITestWithStackView'
    Window (Main), 0x600003009500, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, 0x600003009420, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
        Other, 0x600003009340, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
          Other, 0x600003009260, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
            Other, 0x600003009180, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
              Other, 0x6000030090a0, {{7.0, 348.0}, {400.0, 200.0}}, identifier: 'stackView'
              Other, 0x600003008fc0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                Map, 0x600003008ee0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                Other, 0x600003008e00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
              Link, 0x600003008d20, {{375.4, 841.3}, {28.6, 10.7}}, label: 'Legal'
    Window, 0x600003008c40, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, 0x600003008b60, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
        Other, 0x600003008a80, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
```

Are there any known workarounds for this behavior?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this strange issue. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with nested stack view. In my case it was a stackView with label that was nested in two other stacks.I needed to access labels. Using AccessiblityElements helped to access elements in the lower stack.

```
rootStackView.accesibilityElements[nestedElementsThatNeedToMakeAccessible]
```

If I understood your case correctly, try this

```
stackView.accessibilityElements[view1, view2]
map.accessibilityElements[stackView]
```